# Perl: Get position and length of element in a string

Tags: perl, hash, position

Say I have a string like:

> my $refseq="CCCC-TGA---ATAAAC--TCCAT-GCTCCCCC--------------------AAGC";

I want to detect the positions where "-" occurs and the number of contiguous "-". I want to end up with a hash with "-" position as key, and extension length as value, for this example above:

> %POSLENGTH = (5 => 1, 8 => 3, 14 => 2, 19 => 1, 27 => 20);

Note that the positions should be given based on the string without "-".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for `@-` array in [`perlval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40-)

```
my $refseq = "CCCC-TGA---ATAAAC--TCCAT-GCTCCCCC--------------------AAGC";
my %POSLENGTH;

$POSLENGTH{ $-[0] +1 } = length($1) while $refseq =~ s/(-+)//;

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%POSLENGTH;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = {
      '14' => 2,
      '8' => 3,
      '27' => 20,
      '19' => 1,
      '5' => 1
    };
```

Comment: You're storing the start of the entire match against the length of the first capture. Coincidentally they're the same value, but you really should be using `$-[1] + 1` with `length $1` or `$-[0] + 1` with `$+[0] - $-[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the built-in `@-` and `@+` arrays. Together they hold the start and end offsets of the last successful pattern match in element 0 (and of any captures in elements 1 onwards) so clearly the *length* of the last match is `$+[0] - $-[0]`.
They're documented under *Variables related to regular expressions* in [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions).

I've used `Data::Dump` here just to display the contents of the hash that is built

On a side note, I'm very doubtful that a hash is a useful structure for this information as I can't imagine a situation where you know the start position of a substring and need to know its length. I would have thought it was better represented as just an array of pairs

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

my $refseq="CCCC-TGA---ATAAAC--TCCAT-GCTCCCCC--------------------AAGC";

my %pos_length;

while ( $refseq =~ /-+/g ) {
    my ($pos, $len) = ( $-[0] + 1, $+[0] - $-[0] );
    $pos_length{$pos} = $len;
}

dd \%pos_length;
```

#### output

```
{ 5 => 1, 9 => 3, 18 => 2, 25 => 1, 34 => 20 }
```

Comment: @DaniCee: My apologies, I hadn't noticed that you wanted your start position to start at one instead of zero. It's fixed